How to use a default module and inverter model when they are unknown in PVLib?
Student doing his master's thesis in the field of phtovoltaic here, so I'm new to this topic. I'm creating an algo to detect and classify anomalies in PV systems using only the produced AC Power.
In the 1st step of my algo, I want to simulate the maximum clear sky AC Power of a PV system for anytime of the year.
I know the number of modules, the Wp of each module, the tilt/azimuth, and all informations about the location. However, idk the model of the modules/inverter.
Is it possible to specify a default module and inverter at the creation of a PVSystem?
For example in PVGis you only give the efficiency of the system, and not the model.

If you don't know precisely what components are in the system you can use the
PVWatts module power model
and
PVWatts inverter efficiency model.  All you need to do is provide a nominal power and temperature coefficient for the module, and a nominal efficiency for the inverter.
